# Issues with SetWindowsHookEx on WH_MOUSE_LL from thread - freezes for 5 sec and no trigger

Tags: winapi

My app spawns a thread, in this thread i do the following code:

```
function myLLMouseHook_js(nCode, wParam, lParam) {

    var rez_CallNext = CallNextHookEx(null, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    console.info('rez_CallNext:', rez_CallNext, rez_CallNext.toString());

    return rez_CallNext;
};

aHhk = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, myLLMouseHook_c, null, 0);
```

It registers properly, however for 5 seconds it freezes my mouse, it doesnt move or nothing (keyboard input works at this time). Callback  is never fired. If I attempt unhook on `aHhk` it returns true. It's so odd. The thread is alive and running.

If I run this same code from main thread it works flawlessly. Does anyone hvae any ideas?

Forgive the many issues on this lately, im working on solving one goal of monitoring mouse via multiple (sync/blocking, async/copy of events so non-blockable[the raw input api method was giving probs due to no access to WndProc]) methods to write in tutorials.

Comment: you have to keep an explicit reference to the delegate (directly passing a method by its name will cause errors)? Did you run a message loop (call Appliction.Run or something)?

Comment: Ah thanks @Zotta I think you're right, the thread has no message loop, I'm doing this via ctypes, can you please show a simple thing I can run for message loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely explanation is that the thread is not running a message loop. As [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986.aspx), low level hooks need the hook's owning thread to run a message loop.

> This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop.

Comment: Ahhh I think this is it. Thank you David and @Zotta! Can you please show me a very simple example to get the message loop working, I was checking out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979546/multithreaded-win32-gui-message-loop

Comment: Hey David I got the message loop set up. I registered to recieve raw input events. So this makes my `PeekMessageW` function always get a WM_INPUT. In that same way is it possible to make my PeekMessageW see WM_LBUTTONDOWN etc? Or can I only make it see WM_INPUT? This is how I set it up: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32858206/1828637

Comment: You'll see all queued messages that go to Windows owned by that thread

Comment: Thanks David man, so I created the message only window, with a window proc.  Then I have a message loop that does GetMessage (I don't do DispatchMessage) but I can't seem to set up a SetWindowsHookEx. I was only able to do the RawInput which is async, I wanted to try blocking now. Should I be able to do SetWindowsHookEx for LL_MOUSE now?

Comment: Ah ok thanks man I just hope people don't complain I'm asking so much I'm really learning a ton here.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh you know what it was!! I was just doing a `GetMessage` and not doing `DispatchMessage` thats why it wasnt triggering the low level hook. When i was doing raw mouse events, i was just doing the handling in the message loop without `DispatchMessage`, is this safe for me to do?

Comment: I don't know, whether you are safe to omit DispatchMessage

Comment: No prob Thanks David for fast reply! Btw does GetMessage remove items from queue, so like PeekMessage PM_REMOVE?

Comment: Yes, `GetMessage` always removes. The main difference from `PeekMessage` is that it blocks if the queue is empty, and only returns when a new queued message is available.

Comment: Thanks so much David! It took me sometime but I think im getting this down, things are working now!! :D Open source haha no boss fun fun firefox addons :D Do you use firefox? :D

Comment: @Noitidart No, I really don't like it at all.

Comment: Awww thanks still for helping with it I love this hobby of mine its so constructive. Do you use google chrome?

Comment: Yes, I'm a Chrome guy