# My message loop in thread is not getting any messages

Tags: multithreading, winapi

I have created a thread, I want to listen to mouse messages my app receives.

However `PeekMessage` is never returning true. I even tried min and max filter of 0.

Here is my message loop:

```
PeekMessage(LMessage, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE);

while (true) {
     var rez = PeekMessage(LMessage, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)
     if (rez) {
          // console.log('peekmessage true');
     }
     Sleep 1000;
}

// console.log('message loop eneded');
```

As my hwnd is NULL i thought I should receive all messages to any window in my app, Im not getting anything though. Does anyone know whats up?

I also tried `GetMessage` approach:

```
var rez = GetMessage(LMessage, NULL, 0, 0);
console.log('rez:', rez);
```

However it just hangs and never gets to the `console.log`.

Thanks

Comment: Quoting from the documentation: "If hWnd is NULL, PeekMessage retrieves messages for any window that *belongs to the current thread*".  If that thread hasn't created any windows, it won't get any messages.  (Well, it will get any messages that are posted directly to the thread, but Windows won't do that by itself, you would have to post them yourself.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [`PeekMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943.aspx) says:

> If hWnd is NULL, PeekMessage retrieves messages for any window that **belongs to the current thread**, and any messages on the **current thread's** message queue whose hwnd value is NULL.

[Emphasis Added]

A similar note is in the [`GetMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx) documentation.

The call to `GetMessage` stalls because there is no message queue for the thread, and no messages to wait for, so it will wait forever.

If you need window messages in your thread, have the thread create its own [message-only window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#message_only) and use that as the target for raw input. To create a message-only window call `CreateWindowEx` with `hwndParent` set to `HWND_MESSAGE`.

Otherwise, you'd need to forward messages from your main message loop using [`PostThreadMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928.aspx#posting).

Comment: A message-only window by itself won't help the thread receive mouse messages, though.  The thread is not creating any UI windows that the mouse can interact with.  What you could do, though, is register a [RAW Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) callback for the mouse and tell it to send its [`WM_INPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645590.aspx) messages to the thread's message-only window.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Added some clarification

Comment: Ah darn, that's why. Thanks man so much. So I'm trying to use a thread to monitor mouse messages, in my app or global. I'm trying to stay off of the main thread. I don't understand the part of "use that mesage only window as target for raw input". Can you please help me there. Will both windows get the raw input?

Comment: See [`RegisterRawInputDevices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645600.aspx). The structures that are passed to that function allow you to specify a target HWND for messages.

Comment: Oh wow! Checking out right away thanks @theB my whole issue was I did a `SetWindowsHookEx` it worked from main thread, but for production I need it from a thread and it wans't working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409368/issues-with-setwindowshookex-on-wh-mouse-ll-from-thread-freezes-for-5-sec-and  I think this will be so awesome if RegisterRawInputDevices works! :)

Comment: Working baby! Thanks @theB this is really cool. Async was what I wanted and this gives me async mouse monitoring. For learning and possible application, is it possible to block a mouse event from propagating, like `SetWindowsHookEx` can do with this method?